Webforms file upload automatic saving to /tmp (_sid_) causes vulnerability?
We've recently encountered a potential security issue with Webforms file upload field automatically saving any selected file to /tmp (/_sid_), even when the filesystem is private.
The current file upload field automatically saves any files, selected to be uploaded, to each form's /_sid_ directory and marked as temporary. The file selection triggers a POST request to save the files. If the form is submitted, any unused temporary files are deleted from /_sid_ and the ones selected on the file upload are made permanent. Normally, this works well, because if a user selects files and then abandons the form- the unused temporary files will eventually be deleted by cron.
However, this poses a security vulnerability (even for private file uploads) if malicious users intentionally "select" large amounts of files in the upload field, which are then POSTed to /tmp. This eventually results in a denial-of-service attack as performance begins to degrade when folders have more than 50k files and cron only deletes ~100 /tmp files each time it runs. This action is also not prevented by our current spam control because the forms don't need to be submitted for the files to be uploaded.
This recently happened to our site. We now have over 150k unused temporary files and two folders approaching performance degradation. We had to research methods of manually deleting these files, as it would have taken cron weeks to delete everything, assuming there were no other attacks in the interim.
Our question is: is there a way to prevent this automatic saving? I understand it all currently works as designed, but does this seem like a risk to anyone else?
Secondarily, are there ways to add spam control to the file upload specifically?

Why are you posting security vulnerabilities on stack exchange?

This is probably https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3282721

In fact I think this question is suitable for this site because you are asking for countermeasures.

Might at best be a feature request to Webforms I think. To implement some kind of purger for abandoned forms with some configurable threshold for when a form should be considered abandoned. I think this question belongs in Webform's issue queue,

It has been there a few times already. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3191309, https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3247452

Technically you could write a system-side shell script which could clean those files up fast, and frequently.

if you believe this is a securty issue (which I think it is) it should be reported via the "Report a security vulnerability" link on the webform module page. This question should also be deleted.
